# Make login form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I did a login form with this link http://wplift.com/how-to-create-a-custom-login-page-for-your-wordpress-theme

When I login it redirects to the page of the profile, but I wanted to stay on the same page with a user's session! Is it possible?

I have knowledge in PHP, but it is the first time I am using wordpress and I'm not used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of good login redirect plugins that can be set to return users (based on role, for example) back to the referral page, or to a predetermined page, instead of to the dashboard.

Here's one I've used a few times, it's got some great options

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/